# Javascript: Why the Tab is refresheing , Why not the POP up browser window? Why the pop up browser window is not refreshing?

Tags: javascript, html

Program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function open_win()
            {
              window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","k");
             //window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","k",'width=600,height=600');
            }

            function open_wing()
            {
                window.open("http://www.google.com","k");
                //window.open("http://www.google.com","k",'width=600,height=600');
            }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="W3C" onclick="open_win();">
            <input type="button" value="G" onclick="open_wing();">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My doubt is related to JavaScript.

In the above program i am using k as window name. when we open the above program in browser. we have two buttons W3C and G. click on W3C  new Tab will be opened in browser with w3schools.com and now click on G button. new Tab will not be opened. same Tab containing the weschools will be loaded with google.com. Because window name k is same for both. Its working as expected. but now comment the first line of open_win() and open_wing() , Uncomment second line.open the file on browser. two buttons W3C and G. click on W3C , a window will pop up from the browser having w3schools.com. and now click on G , new window will open. i want the same window opened for w3schools.com should be refreshed(as it was working for Tabs, not working for pop up browser windows.) Finally the Question is ,Why the Tab is refresheing , Why not the POP up browser window? Why the pop up browser window is not refreshing ?

Please help.
        Thanks,
      krishna

Comment: Please reformat the code, remove the comments, it's not really readable

Comment: Can you show where your code is, or us a jsbin/jsfiddle. its not very clear what you have got, so its hard to offer a solution

Comment: Hi. The functionality you are wanting is what Im getting when I add the code to a jsBin. what browser are you using?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win()
{
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","k");
//window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","k",'width=600,height=600');
}
function open_wing()
{
window.open("http://www.google.com","k");
//window.open("http://www.google.com","k",'width=600,height=600');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="W3C" onclick="open_win();">
<input type="button" value="G" onclick="open_wing();">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

In

```
window.open("http://www.google.com","k");
```

> URL    Optional. Specifies the URL of the page to open. If no URL is specified, a new window with about:blank is opened
>
> name   Optional. Specifies the target attribute or the name of the window. The following values are supported:
>
> _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
>
> _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
>
> _self - URL replaces the current page
>
> _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
>
> name - The name of the window

in your case you are passing `K as window Name`. if there is already a window open with name `K` it will be used..

If you want to open new window always... 
use

window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");

or

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

As per comment 
the code mentioned is working correctly
There is no error..

http://jsfiddle.net/CuUDA/

Comment: K is the window name.Its already opened for w3schools.com.Its not reloading or refreshing with google.com when i clicked on button G.Instead a new widow is opening with google.com. i want to refresh the same window of w3schools.com with google.com.

Comment: check if its a ny browser specific issue or all browsers

Comment: Except IE 8.0.760 , all other browsers its working as expected.

Comment: @krishna then it is very important part of question. please update question with this details

Comment: function submitme() 
{
      var loNewWin;
      var lsWindowName = 'winname' ;
      alert(lsWindowName);
      loNewWin = window.open('', lsWindowName,
                'no' , 'no' , 'no', 'yes' , 'no',
                'yes', 'yes', null,
                  null, 0, 0, 'yes' );
       document.SSOForm.target = lsWindowName;
  document.SSOForm.submit(); 
} The program which i gave in the starting of the thread is an example. This code is opening two seperate window instead of refreshing the same window. Why? please help